# Service account API error when getting the access token

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-developers-console, google-people-api

I am testing google people API for our web application.
Steps:

- I created new project in the google console (https://console.cloud.google.com/)
- I enabled People API
- I created needed Credentials - web client for my application and API key
- I created service account with p12 key for server to server queries and enabled "Google Workspace Domain-wide Delegation"
- I configured OAuth consent screen with scopes needed to authorize to google and get access to people API: /auth/userinfo.email /auth/userinfo.profile /auth/contacts /auth/contacts.readonly
- Then my PHP script using "Google API PHP client" make redirect link to consent screen and return code for access token with Web client:

```
<?php

$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setAccessType('online'); // default: offline
$client->setApplicationName('My Project xxxxx');
$client->setClientId('999999999999-qwertysdfhwe9uriiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('GOCSPX-hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh');                
$client->setDeveloperKey('AIzafffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff'); // API key

$client->setState('subdomain.myapp.com');

$scriptUri = 'https://oauth.myapp.com/auth.php';
$client->setRedirectUri($scriptUri);

$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts');
                
$auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();

header('Location: '.$auth_url);

?>
```

This code redirects to google Authentication screen, then I login with google and approve scopes. Google redirects me back to my app and now I have access token and aproved scopes and email of authenticated user.

The next step I have huge trouble - server - to - server query to get access token for people API

```
function base64_url_encode($input) {
    return str_replace('=', '', strtr(base64_encode($input), '+/', '-_'));
}

$iat = time();      

$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";        

$scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts';

$jwt_data = array(
    'iss' => '111111111111111111111', // My service account ID
    'aud' => $url,
    'scope' => $scope,
    'exp' => $iat + 3600,
    'iat' => $iat,
    'sub' => 'user@gmail.com', // Email of the user that was autenticated in first step
);

openssl_pkcs12_read(file_get_contents('keyfile.p12'), $certs, 'notasecret');
$header = array('typ' => 'JWT', 'alg' => 'RS256');
$signing_input = base64_url_encode(json_encode($header)) . '.' . base64_url_encode(json_encode($jwt_data));
openssl_sign($signing_input, $signature, $certs['pkey'], 'SHA256');
$jwt = $signing_input . '.' . base64_url_encode($signature);

$data = array(
    "grant_type" => "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
    "assertion" => $jwt
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$google_contacts_api_tokens_collection[$use_mailbox] = $response;

return $response;
```

And this code google returns the error that I can not fix, and I have no any ideas.

The text of error:
"Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested."

Comment: Are the users Google Accounts users (Gmail) or Google Workspace users? You can only impersonate the second type of user.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to impersonate a user via a service account. This requires enabling Domain Wide Delegation. In a round-about way, the error message means the service account does not have permission because delegation is not enabled.

[Perform Google Workspace Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)

If the user is not part of Google Workspace, then you cannot impersonate the user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but I already tried this and it does not help. I configured scopes for service account in the Google Workspace, and also checked the "Enable Google Workspace Domain-wide Delegation" checkbox in google console. In Google Workspace I used digital Client ID of my service account.

And also I discovered one strange moment:

- Web client always returns good access token, but when I request service account access token it works well only for google console project owner ('sub' => 'project.owner@gmail.com'). And if I request service account access token for another user ('sub' => 'project.testuser@gmail.com') Google also returns the same error: `Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.`